# What Marvel universe is Archie's?

Tags: marvel

I know Marvel likes to make a lot of alternate universes. I was wondering since the Archie Meets the Punisher comics were a crossover between Marvel and Archie, did Marvel dedicate a universe to those comics?

Answer (score 2):

The best resource I know of offhand for Marvel's official universe numbers is from the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Multiverse/Universe_Listing). It does not list an official universe number for the Archie/Punisher crossover.

(The editors of the wikia haven't even bothered to give it their own "temporary" reality number, which they typically do when they think Marvel might eventually assign one.)

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Archie_Meets_the_Punisher_Vol_1_1 - Ahem, it lists Earth-616.

Comment: It also cites no reference for the supposed Earth-616 reality.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's saying that the Marvel characters are the versions from Earth-616, but the wiki article uses lists what universe in the sidebar...

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-7642), and [this website](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix3/earthcrossoverall.htm), it takes place on Earth-7642. That would make sense, as it is the official crossover universe where Marvel, DC, Archie and other comic franchises all co-exist.

Unfortunately though, I can find no official word on it.